# replacing some fields in a line with the fields in the same columns in the next line

Tags: python, perl, awk, sed

How can I parse the following tab delimited file to see if the 5th field is empty or not and if it is empty, replace c1 with c2 and d1 with d2. The actual file has a large number of rows with some having their 5th field empty.

```
a0  b0  c0  d0  e0
a1  b1  c1  d1  e1
a2  b2  c2  d2  
a3  b3  c3  d3  e3
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you want to change the line before the lines with an empty/missing 5th field?

Comment: @ikegami There is no need to change the fields in the existing line unless the fifth field in the next line is empty. I am new to bash scripts.

Comment: Save to a new file? Print? This is a little unclear...

Comment: @dawg If saved to a new file, how can one replace c1 and d1 in one file with c2 and d2 in another file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
$ cat so.txt
a0  b0  c0  d0  e0
a1  b1  c1  d1  e1
a2  b2  c2  d2  
a3  b3  c3  d3  e3
```

You can write a filter in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import fileinput
from collections import deque
d=deque(maxlen=1)
for line in fileinput.input():
    sp=line.split()
    if len(sp)==4 and d:
        d[-1][2]=sp[2]
        d[-1][3]=sp[3]
    else:   
        if d: print '\t'.join(d[-1])
        d.append(sp)
else:
    print '\t'.join(d[-1])
```

Since the [deque](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) is specified with max length of 1, it will only hold 1 line in memory at any given time. That means this filter will never have more than two lines in memory.

Then:

```
$ ./so.py so.txt
a0  b0  c0  d0  e0
a1  b1  c2  d2  e1
a3  b3  c3  d3  e3
```

And redirect that to the desired file.

Notes: will not work if there are multiples lines in a row that are only four fields or if the first line has four fields. You did not specify those results however...

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create a lookahead buffer of one line.

1. Read a line and save it as "Current Line".
2. While there are more lines to read,

   1. Read a line and save it as "Next Line".
   2. If the Next Line has a missing or empty fifth field,

      1. Modify the Current Line appropriately.
   3. Print the Current Line.
   4. Make the Next Line to the Current Line.
3. Print the Current Line.